# Iterate over a spark dataframe and create a nested json string

Tags: sql, json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having a dataframe with the below details and I need to iterate over each row to create the below formatted nested json string.

| Employee name | Salary | sick_leave_day | paid_leave_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Karthi | 20000 | 10-10-2021 | Y |
| Karthi | 20000 | 11-12-2021 | Y |
| Karthi | 20000 | 13-12-2021 | N |
| Rajesh | 25000 | 15-12-2021 | Y |
| Rajesh | 25000 | 17-11-2021 | N |
| Rajesh | 25000 | 10-10-2021 | Y |

The output json should look like below, Here, `Name` and `salary` is having unique data and `sick_leave_day`,`paid_leave_day` changes for each row.

```json
{
    "Name": "Karthi",
    "Salary": "20000",
    leave_details: [{
            "sick_leave_day": "10-10-2021",
            "paid_leave_day ": "Y"
        },
        {
            "sick_leave_day": "11-12-2021",
            "paid_leave_day ": "Y"
        },
        {
            "sick_leave_day": "13-12-2021",
            "paid_leave_day ": "N"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried to iterate over dataframe using `foreach` method, but I'm unable to get the logic. If I group the name and salary, I can't get the value of name and salary only once. So, please help me to write the logic by iterating over each row to create this logic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#collect_list(columnName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) aggregation function to group by Employee and get the list of leave days.

For instance you can manually create a JSON with the 2 "leave_day" columns then aggregate using collect_list:

```scala
var result = df.withColumn("new_col", concat(lit("{ sick_leave_day:"), df.col("sick_leave_day"), lit(", paid_leave_day:"), df.col("paid_leave_day"), lit("}")))
    .groupBy("Employee name", "Salary")
    .agg(collect_list("new_col"))

result.show(truncate=false)
```

```
+-------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Employee name|Salary|collect_list(new_col)                                                                                                                           |
+-------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Rajesh       |25000 |[{ sick_leave_day:15-12-2021, paid_leave_day:Y}, { sick_leave_day:17-11-2021, paid_leave_day:N}, { sick_leave_day:10-10-2021, paid_leave_day:Y}]|
|Karthi       |20000 |[{ sick_leave_day:10-10-2021, paid_leave_day:Y}, { sick_leave_day:11-12-2021, paid_leave_day:Y}, { sick_leave_day:13-12-2021, paid_leave_day:N}]|
+-------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by `Employee name` and collect list of structs for `leave_details` array and first (or max) `Salary` then save a json:

```scala
val result = df.groupBy(col("Employee name").as("name")).agg(
    first($"Salary").as("Salary"),
    collect_list(struct($"sick_leave_day", $"paid_leave_day")).as("leave_details")
)

result.toJSON.collect.foreach(println(_))

//{"name":"Rajesh","Salary":"25000","leave_details":[{"sick_leave_day":"15-12-2021","paid_leave_day":"Y"},{"sick_leave_day":"17-11-2021","paid_leave_day":"N"},{"sick_leave_day":"10-10-2021","paid_leave_day":"Y"}]}
//{"name":"Karthi","Salary":"20000","leave_details":[{"sick_leave_day":"10-10-2021","paid_leave_day":"Y"},{"sick_leave_day":"11-12-2021","paid_leave_day":"Y"},{"sick_leave_day":"13-12-2021","paid_leave_day":"N"}]}
```